# How Do I Re-Open the Entity Framework 6.1 Wizard to Add More Tables?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Framework 6.1 'Code From Database' based project and now I need to add more tables from the database to my code.

I've spent an hour now trying to figure out how to open the Wizard to add more tables to my project.

Am I missing something or are we not able to modify a 'Code from Database' project to bring in more tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to edit an existing 'Code from Database' import. I ended up creating the new POCOs by adding a new data model and then deleting the newly created DbContext after moving it's DbSet<> properties into my existing DbContext.

This was quite easy to do but I was only adding a couple of tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new item to your project: Visual C# -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Select Code First from Database, select the objects needed and it will generate a model class (DBSets, Fluent config, etc) and the POCOs. I've got a big database I've been bringing over in chunks that way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Comment: This is add new not edit existing. You are getting also getting new DBContext classes generated each time you do this...correct? I want to add new tables to my existing DbContext class.

Comment: I have my existing Context and POCOs in separate folders (or projects). Then I do the above process to bring a new group of tables in and it will create a new model and POCOs which I move or edit into my existing classes. A little work, but way better than coding it all by hand. You can also customize the Context and EntityType T4 templates if needed.

Comment: I'm using migrations which get cluttered after a while, but I will occasionally roll them up into a single migration to keep things looking cleaner.